# Image Zoom, Pan and Sliced images

Tags: android, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I have a image received from server. I have to provide Zoom and Pan functionality to it.
I also receive set of point of image, when clicked on these point of image i need to show a pop up.

Initially i thought of using default viewer for image but the pop up of click of specific point is out of question.

I cannot slice the image also

Point me to proper direction.

Comment: why "click of specific point is out of question." ?

Comment: if i use default viewer, how i can i create a pop up when specific point is clicked!!!

Comment: I think this should be make clear "in google maps app, we have map which can be zoomed and panned and there is also specific points, say a hospital which is clicked opens a balloon pop and displays info". i need the same but for different application.

Comment: ok, so what have you tried and what problem do you have with?

Comment: Point me to proper direction... i needed inputs to decide on which method to use.

Comment: the easiest. is to find a custom component that supports pan and zoom featutes, then try to integrate it with your app and then if you have some problems ask a question here

Answer (score 1):

I think this library fulfills your requirements: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView